# Psoc Cypress Monitoring Capsense Button Actions

Tags: microcontroller, uart, capsense

I am too new on Psoc Cypress. I have a basic aim but I could not figure it out.

Yes there is a tool to monitor capsense values in a graph etc. But my aim is monitoring ADC values of any capacitive button. Can you give me an example code for a button to print a buttons capacitive buttons ADC values in UART serial screen? My total aim is sending capsense button ADC values to a Nodemcu to show values in a MQTT platform.

Answer (score 0):

Here is approximately your code. I leave you fill the function since that is a good learning!

```
main{
init_uart();
init_adc();
        
while(1)
{
if(adc_conversion() == IS_COMPLETE)
{
    uart_write(adc_value());
    wait(100ms);
    start_adc_conversion();
}}
```